# Getting Warning sign : OMEGA13 was used but was never set (will evaluate as its name)

Tags: automation, ui-automation, eggplant

Getting warning from Script Checker : "OMEGA13 was used but was never set (will evaluate as its name)"

I've set

```
start using Omega13

-- some codes here --

stop using Omega13
```

Anyone has any idea on why the warning sign is there?

[Eggplant documentation - Advance scripting: Error Recovery with Omega13](http://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/using/epf-error-recovery-with-omega13.htm)

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happened is somewhere you've mistyped some variant of `omega13`.

Sensetalk treats uninitialized variables as strings. This results in lots of hard to debug errors.

```
name = "my name"
put naame
```

This will print `naame` which is probably not what you wanted.

---

It looks like the correct form to invoke is `omega13` not `Omega13`, or `OMEGA13`. I'd check the documentation and make sure that you haven't mistyped it anywhere.

You may also want to look into the [strictVariables](http://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-variables.htm#undefined-variables-and-the-strictvariables-global-property-anchor) global which if true will treat using an uninitialized variable as an error.

Comment: but the documentation's example of script was "Omega13" hmm also, eggplant isn't case sensitive..

Comment: EggPlant's documentation isn't the best, there are lots of poorly explained features. Looking closer at the documentation the examples use `omega13` and `Omega13` interchangeably. I'd forgotten how permissive they're variables can be. What I can say for sure is that script checker is treating omega13 as an uninitialized variable. If it runs correctly than it's script checker not handling omega13 correctly. If omega13 doesn't run then it's somehow not getting made available in global scope when it should be.

Comment: hmm it did work properly. i guess i can just ignore the warning sign by the script checker.. thanks btw..